# Why doesn't adding a link or image to my signature work?

Tags: outlook.com, email-signature

I have a business email account hooked up to Outlook.com (as a POP email / send from address). I'm trying to add a rich signature with social media links.

When I add an `<a>` or `<img>` tag in the HTML editor on the Outlook.com signatures page, it appears to work. However, once saved, the target of the `<a>` tag gets rewritten to `_blank`. The `<img>` tags get rewritten to `<i_blank.gif>`.

I guess that Outlook.com is sanitizing the signature (anti-spam?) without telling me (thanks Outlook.com!). Is there anyway to stop this from happening?